# Dependency Injection - Dagger2 - Generics

Tags: java, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I am having problems injecting a generic type interface. Not sure how to do this or google it since I don't know the exact terms to search for. Sorry if i'm completely wrong just getting started with dagger.

Basically I have a use case class

```
public class LoadConversations<C extends IConversation>
    extends UseCase<List<C>, LoadConversations.Type> {

    private final IConversationRepository<C> messageRepository;

    @Inject LoadConversations(@NonNull IConversationRepository<C> messageRepository) {
        this.messageRepository = messageRepository;
    }

    ....

    public enum Type {
        ALL, NEWER, OLDER
    }
}
```

With `IConversationRepository` being an interface.

```
public interface IConversationRepository<C extends IConversation> {
    Observable<List<C>> conversations(LoadConversations.Type params);
}
```

`IConversation` being a blank interface and `ConversationModule` where i provide the `IConversationRepository`.

Im having problems injecting with the following code. Am i missing something or doing something completey wrong. Thanks in advance.

Trying to provide as follows:

```
@Provides IConversationRepository<Conversation> provideConversationRepository(
        ConversationRepository conversationRepository) {
    return conversationRepository;
}
```

And I'm trying to inject this to my presenter as

```
private final LoadConversations<Conversation> loadConversations;

@Inject public ConversationListPresenter(LoadConversations<Conversation> loadConversations) {
    this.loadConversations = loadConversations;
}
```

Implementation of `ConversationRepository`

```
public class ConversationRepository implements IConversationRepository<Conversation> {
    @Override public Observable<List<Conversation>> conversations(LoadConversations.Type params) {
        ....
    }
}
```

Error Log:

```
Error:(15, 10) error: com.rbttalk.android.data.repository.ConversationRepository cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides-annotated method.
com.rbttalk.android.data.repository.ConversationRepository is injected at
com.rbttalk.android.di.module.sub_modules.ConversationModule.provideConversationRepository(conversationRepository)
com.rbttalk.android.domain.repository.IConversationRepository<com.rbttalk.android.domain.models.Conversation> is injected at
com.rbttalk.android.domain.usecase.conversation.LoadConversations.<init>(arg0, …)
com.rbttalk.android.domain.usecase.conversation.LoadConversations<com.rbttalk.android.domain.models.Conversation> is injected at
com.rbttalk.android.ui.main.conversation.ConversationListPresenter.<init>(loadConversations)
com.rbttalk.android.ui.main.conversation.ConversationListPresenter is injected at
com.rbttalk.android.ui.main.conversation.ConversationListFragment.userListPresenter
com.rbttalk.android.ui.main.conversation.ConversationListFragment is injected at
com.rbttalk.android.di.component.ConversationComponent.inject(conversationListFragment)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're very close! The error message says it all:

> com.rbttalk.android.data.repository.ConversationRepository cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides-annotated method.

Note that this is not IConversationRepository; you've provided a binding for that with your `@Provides` method (which you can eventually consider [converting to a @Binds method](https://google.github.io/dagger//faq.html#why-is-binds-different-from-provides)). However, that @Provides method has a parameter, `ConversationRepository`, which effectively asks Dagger to create an instance of that concrete ConversationRepository type for you. You've made that binding correctly, but now Dagger needs to instantiate ConversationRepository for you, and it simply doesn't know how.

You'll need to create an `@Inject`-annotated constructor for ConversationRepository using the annotation type `javax.inject.Inject`, even if it just looks like this:

```
@Inject ConversationRepository() {}
```

This allows Dagger to know that yes, it is safe to call that constructor. (This differs from Guice, which was willing to call a public parameterless constructor including the default constructor provided by Java.) Though you are welcome to accept injector-provided parameters in that annotated constructor (which might be nice if your repository has dependencies, because then you can keep the fields `final`), you may also choose to simply annotate some fields with `@Inject` and let the injector populate those after creation.

Comment: Great explanation. I did realize the mistake but you made it very clear why it was needed.